# Spark 3 unable to read from MongoDB view

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark, view

Trying to read MongoDB view from Spark 3 and it returns error.

**com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 166 (CommandNotSupportedOnView): 'Namespace xxxxxxxxxxx.my_view is a view, not a collection' on server xxxxxxxxxxx:27017.**

Here's the code:

```
wdf = (
  spark.read
  .format("mongo")
  .option("database", database)
  .option("spark.mongodb.input.uri", connection_str)
  .option("collection", collection)
  .load()
)
wdf.createOrReplaceTempView("temp")
```

I'm using Mongo connector **org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.12:3.0.1**, also tried **org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.12:10.1.1** but both returned same error.

I tried with pymongo python package & it works.

So, Is there a way to read MongoDB view using Spark?